# intents.matches() being automatically executed without any input

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm using an `IntentDialog` with a `LuisRecognizer` for natural language input.

After my `/firstRun` dialog, I replace the dialog with `session.replaceDialog('/')` to listen for inputs, like this:

```
bot.dialog('/firstRun', [
  function (session) {
    session.send('Hi, its nice to meet you, i\'m a Bot.')
    builder.Prompts.text(session, 'So anyway, whats your name?');
  }, function(session, results) {
     session.userData.name = results.response
     session.send('Another message')
     session.replaceDialog('/');
   }
]);
```

Heres that dialog: `bot.dialog('/', intents);`

Now what happens is, once `session.replaceDialog('/')` is called and my `/firstRun` finishes, one of my Intents gets fired off, WITHOUT any input.

For example, heres one of my intents:

```
intents.matches('MyIntent', [
  function (session, args, next) {
    console.log('My Intent has been called')
  },
])
```

So the question is: Without any input, how/why is an Intent being matched?

Comment: Bot Framework has undergone major improvements since this question was asked.  Are you still experiencing the issue with [botbuilder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder) v3.8.0?

Comment: I haven't worked on this project for some time.